# How to show in pop up box message in D7

Tags: blocks, javascript

I am developing custom module in D7. And created one custom block. And how can show the conent in the block as pop up box?sample block code is  `

> $block['content'] = t('Test message');

I want show 'Test message' as in pop up..

`

Answer (score 1):

There are several modules that you may be able to use or deconstruct to help with your custom module.

- [Popup](http://drupal.org/project/popup) (**D7**)
- [Lightbox2](http://drupal.org/project/lightbox2) (D6, **D7**)
- [Shadowbox](http://drupal.org/project/shadowbox) (D5, D6, **D7**)
- [Popups (AJAX)](http://drupal.org/project/popups) (D6)

Answer (score 0):

There is the [Popup message](https://drupal.org/project/popup_message) module which provides you the same functionality as you need.

From the module's project page:

> Display popup message for users once per browser session.
>
> Based on javascript code: http://yensdesign.com/2008/09/how-to-create-a-stunning-and-smooth-popup-using-jquery/