# how to show message in popup when user register to site?

Tags: theming

I just want to show message in popup when user register to site."Further instructions have been sent to your e-mail address". This message i want to show in pop-up.

Comment: Read this :http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/40793/how-to-show-in-pop-up-box-message-in-d7

Answer (score 2):

Use this module to show popup on the specific page.Use the latest dev version https://drupal.org/project/popup_message

Answer (score 0):

You can check [Better message](https://drupal.org/project/better_messages) module for this purpose.

From the module's project page:

> Better Messages is a very simple module that provides "Popup-like" Drupal messages.
>
> Better Messages intends to let you control where and how you want to see your Drupal messages! Combine different animations and override `better_messages.tpl.php` to create your custom look.